How to design a simple 10 band stereo equalizer without any display?
I was trying to build a 10 band stereo equalizer where I would implement 10 bandpass filters centered at frequencies 32, 64, 128,256m....,16.384 kHz for a simulation project
I used a -40 dB and a +40 dB butterworth filters cascaded together and then the output is passed through a potentiometer to an inverting amplifier. I wanted to control the boost or attenuate a certain band by sliding the potentiometer. For the filters I used opamp-177 (I don't have any reasonable idea to use this one I saw it being used in the book authored by Coughlin in the filters section). I tried to simulate this circuit both in Proteus and Pspice. But I failed due to voltage and current not converging in Pspice. On the other hand cpu load exceeds in proteus after a while and also I noticed that even though the dc bias of each opamp is at 15V the output somehow seems to saturate way below 1V when .wav file was given as input
I want to know whether this idea of utilizing the filters  to create equalizer a good idea or not? (Since I don't have indepth knowledge about filter circuits I just studied butterworth filters recently and I don't have much knowledge on different types of opamp either like which one to use in which application). Also how to overcome the issues in those SPICE softwares?


This is a slightly different circuit instead of using 40 dB filters I used 60 dB filters(basically cascading a 40 dB butterworth with a 20 dB filter). All the values were calculated considering a center freq of 32 Hz and 64 Hz bandwidth.
And here is the gain vs frequency plot of this circuit:

EDIT:
I've tried to implement all the 10 bands together
But this time used 2 -40 dB and 2 +40 dB Butterworth filters to create a single bandpass filter.

The gain vs frequency plot of this circuit:

That red irregular curve is the output after summing all the band outputs. I didn't quite understand why their sum is that low? Could it be because of the phase?

Show us how are you handling just one of the bandpass filters, with gain adjustment, while retaining the Butterworth behavior. I'd like to see what you are using to get there.

I've edited the question and added image of the single channel implementation in pspice

To save me analysis time, can you provide your transfer function of this stage -- one, in particular, that shows the gain is independent of $Q$/$\zeta$? And how are you controlling the gain with a potentiometer here?

I am not much familiar with these terms all I know at this point is that Q is the quality. I can add the gain vs frequency plot

I have edited the question again

Have you looked at National Semiconductor's (now Texas Instruments) Graphic Equalizer application note: AN-435? National Semiconductor's Audio Radio Handbook also has a section on a 10-band equalizer on page 2-59 which is similar to AN-435.

@MSKB If you want the filter shape in each band to remain independent of the gain set for that band, my gut tells me that you may want to familiarize yourself with either or both of state variable and/or biquad filter stages. (Very similar.) Both the 3- and also the 4- opamp versions. (The 4 opamp one includes a feedback stage to compensate for shape changes due to gain changes.) I'm sure there are also more nuanced and sophisticated behavioral models I'm not aware of which use fewer parts to get to the same place. But I'd suggest studying the state variable/biquad structure, first.

@MSKB Also, you need to be aware that using resistances into the megOhm range is going to depend heavily on unmanaged offset and bias currents and other parasitics. You need to design for part values that aren't so affected.

I'm trying to redesign(change the capacitance and resistance) the entire equalizer and then check out the gain vs frequency plot again

One could try and handle this numerically. Even latency/delay looks less of a problem. than in the last millennium.

I tried to implement what type of circuit I was thinking of but I guess it didn't quite perform like a equalizer

There is an issue with Pspice AC sweep if we give an input more than the dc bias of the opamp it should practically saturate at a lower voltage than the dc bias but Pspice doesn't follow that rather they just simply scale that even if the input is more than the saturation voltage and therefore the output is also larger than saturation voltage
